# How to replace Vuetify scss font styles?

Tags: vue.js, sass, vuetify.js

in src/scss/variables.scss

```
@import '~vuetify/src/styles/styles.sass';

 $headings: (
      'h1': (
      'size': 36px,
      'line-height': 36px,
    ),
     'h2': (
    'size': 24px,
    'line-height': 24px
  ),
  'h3': (
    'size': 1.5625rem,
    'line-height': 1.4em
  ),
  'h4': (
    'size': 1.125rem,
    'line-height': 1.4em
  ),
  'h5': (
    'size': 1.0625rem
  ),
  'h6': (
    'size': .75rem
  ),
  'subtitle-2': (
    'size': 1rem
  ),
  'overline': (
    'letter-spacing': 0
  )
);
```

end result:

```
.v-application .display-4 {
    font-size: 36px !important;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 36px;
    letter-spacing: -.015625em !important;
    font-family: "Lora", serif !important;
}
```

but instead of replacing the variables, i get the definitions in the base variables merged in.
Is this because it is using deep-merge and it gets merged after i defined my styles?

```
in vuetify/src/style/settings/_variables.scss
$headings: map-deep-merge(
  (
    'h1': (
      'size': 6rem,
      'weight': 300,
      'line-height': 6rem,
      'letter-spacing': -.015625em,
      'font-family': $heading-font-family
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the same issue, and finally found the solution, it's really easy...

You just need to import styles.sass at the bottom of the file. This way, You'll override the default variable while Vuetify merges your custom variable with the default map $headings.